# how to use math in c++

Tags: c++, math

When I give my n a value of 1 why does the result equal to 2 and not 3. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    float result;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    result = 1 + n/(2*n+1)*3/2;
    while (n != 1)
    {
        result = result*(n-1)/(2*(n-1)+1);
        n = n-1;
    }
    result = result * 2;
    printf("%f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integer division - dividing an `int` by an `int` gives a result of type `int`, with rounding towarded zero.   So (in the first calculation of `result`)  if `n` is `1`, the calculation `n/(2+n+1)` becomes equivalent to `1/3`, which gives zero.     The fact that `result` is of type `float` does not change that.

Comment: Integer division is not the same as floating point division. Writing code is not the same as pure maths.

Comment: C or C++? _Pick one_.

Comment: @Peter Don't answer in comments

Comment: Many similar questions involving integer division. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610932/c-rounding-error

Comment: OT: `stdio.h`, `scanf()`, and `printf()` are all C language facilities.   `cstdio`, `cin()` and `cout()` are C++ features.   Suggest removing the `c++` tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `n` is an `int`, the math on the right side is done as integer math, not float. Then the results is promoted to float to  store into `result`.

```
result = 1 + n/(2*n+1)*3/2;
result = 1 + 1/3*3/2;
result = 1 + 1;
result = float(2);
```

Use `float` constants to get it to actually calculate as a float.

```
result =1.0f + n/(2.0f*n+1.0f)*3.0f/2.0f;
```